# Randomly selecting records and grouping(randomly partitioning rows)

Tags: mysql, random, laravel-5

Hi I have staff table and i want to assign them to different Department randomly
let suppose staff table structure like this

```
id  staffname 
1   A    
2   B    
3   C    
4   D    
5   E    
6   F    
7   G    
8   H    
9   I
```

Any Idea?? how do i select staff randomly and assign them to multiple group so that no staff will repeat in a Dept for example

**Dept 1**

```
 id  staffname 
 3   C        
 5   E    
 6   F       
 9   I
```

**Dept 2**

```
id  staffname 
1   A        
4   D   
7   G
```

**Dept 3**

```
id  staffname 
1   A    
2   B    
8   H
```

I am trying to do this in Laravel/Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods random and diff from Collection.
Considering that you will search all Staff entities, try something like this:

```
$staff = Staff::all();

$i = 0;
while($staff->count() > 0) {
   $random = $staff->random(3);
   foreach($random as $s) {
      $s->departament_id = $i;
   }
   $staff = $staff->diff($random);
   $i++;
}
```

Of course that you need to check departament_id before saving, or even creating one inside the method, but that's the idea.

I hope it helps...

Comment: Ok! Tell me if it fits your question